# print a string from an input but also add the number to the end of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to input a number, then word and have the output reflect the word+number.  So far I can get it to print the word but am lost as to how to add the number to the end.

```py
times = input('How many?')
word = input('Enter your word:')

print(''.join([word] * int(times)))
```

So if I input

```
How many? 4
Enter your word: test
```

The output would be

```
test1, test2, test3, test4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, am very new to python.  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried _to do the thing that you want to do?!_ And what is wrong with _that attempt?_ From the code you have shared, it doesn't even look like you've made an effort to append the number to the word. Why do you expect that code to give you the output you want?

Comment: Hint: Whenever you have to do the same thing a number of times, you need to think of a loop. This "thing" that you want to do is append a number to a string. This number increases by one every time, so you want this number to be the loop variable. Then you need to look up how you can append a number to a string.

Comment: Spent the last few hours on google and only got to that point, no search led to f-strings so I'm attempting to grow more of an understanding so I can more efficiently search.  Hence why I said am very new to python. Didn't see how including failed google search attempts would bring anyone closer to an answer.  I have about 3 days experience on python, but thanks for your comment I'll attempt to include more information in future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Python there is a thing called f-strings, they automatically format your string.
So you can rewrite it as this:

```
times = int(input("How many? "))
word = input("Enter your word: ")
printStr = ""

for i in range(times):
    printStr += f"{word}{i+1}, "

printStr = printStr[:-2] # This cuts off the last comma and space
print(printStr)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Spent a while trying to find exactly this.  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Using f-strings and `str.join`:

```
>>> times = 4
>>> word = "test"
>>> ", ".join(f"{word}{n}" for n in range(1, times+1))
'test1, test2, test3, test4'
```